# How many 1024*1024 pngs can be load in openGL for iphone without having the app crash in the device ??

Tags: iphone, opengl, textures

Approximately what's the maximum number of 1024x1024 32 bit .pngs  which can be loaded at the same time with openGL in iphone ?, without risk of the app crashing.

And  .pvr ? a much higher number ?

If I need a huge amount of textures in my game, is healthy to keep loading and calling dealloc to not overload the memory with all the textures ?

Comment: This may sound nuts, but why do you need 1024x1024 textures on a device whose resolution is 480x320? Reduce the texture size to something more appropriate for the device, including screen, power and memory requirements. Those of us who kept our 3G when the 3GS came out will thank you. :)

Comment: Because  those textures work as sprite sheets, they contain different animations and visual elements which I need to be able to drawn at any moment during gameplay, and a 480X320 wouldnt be enough.

Comment: Jose: OK, that makes much more sense; you're right -- for that use case 480x320 isn't enough. Your correct answer is essentially Ben S's -- you want to load & unload dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should load textures as required and unload unused textures when your application receives a low memory warning.

To answer your maximum memory question, it seems that the iPhone 2G/3G gives memory warnings around the 20 MB mark and iPhone 3GS starts to give warnings around 128 MB.

```
1024 * 1024 * 32 bits = 4 MB
```

So that's  about 5 textures loaded before you get warnings. **1024 x 1024 is quite large** (it's the largest you can have AFAIK) for a texture, so if possible you should **reduce their size**.

*Note: My warning threshold values aren't official, they're just from experience and from other questions on stackoverflow.*

Comment: Sounds like my best option is to either use 24 bit pngs
 1024*1024*24= 3MB or even 16 bit pngs 1024*1024*16= 2MB. But each of those formats supports alpha ? ( since my sprite sheets contain all the sprites of the game, i really need the alpha !)

Comment: Your best option is, as Ben mentions here, to load and unload as required. Manage the memory! :)

Answer (score 5):

`PVRTC` can be used with either 2 or 4 bits per texel, which is a *huge* saving. It's not possible to give a specific number for the amount of texture memory which is safe to use. Apple really dropped the ball on this, see [this](http://gamesfromwithin.com/whered-that-memory-go) and [this](http://gamesfromwithin.com/i-want-my-memory-apple) articles from Noel Lopis.

Also remember that if you're using mipmaps it takes 33% more memory (each mipmap is 1/4 of the level above => 1 + 1 / 4 + 1 / 16... ~= 1.33).

**EDIT:** One more note `PVRTC` doesn't work well if you have a very distinct alpha mask that you want to preserve.

Answer (score 2):

I hope when you say "and calling dealloc" you mean "and releasing those objects with -release" because you should never ever call -dealloc on any object yourself.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but still a valid point.